# Getting Started with DCM4CHEE Source Code: Need Expert Advice

Tags: java

I'm attempting to run the DCM4CHEE source code locally for development purposes. I've successfully cloned the repository and configured the necessary settings,Issues Deploying DCM4CHEE: Looking for Step-by-Step Instructions. I want expert advise for how we can run the source code.Help Needed in Running the Source Code.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: so the question is not about the Java Programing Language, as indicated by the [tag:java] tag, but how to deploy and run DCM4CHEE... I would try its [homepage](https://www.dcm4che.org/), mainly the Google Group and Wiki links there -- anyway the question is too broad for StackOverflow, please complete the [tour] and check [ask]